# How do i change the property of jaxrs endpoint to support "mtom"

Tags: rest, cxf, mtom

I created a RESTful web service, and I want to send binary files to this service without SOAP.

There are some information on CXF website:
[XOP](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-XOPsupport)

But I can't find a way to get the CXF JAX-RS endpoints, and set an `mtom-enabled` property.

My Spring config is:

```xml
<jaxrs:server id="fis" address="http://172.20.41.40:8080/fis">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="FaultInfoResource" />
        <ref bean="ExplorationResultResource" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>  
</jaxrs:server> 

<bean id="FaultInfoService"  parent="baseService" class="com.dfe.demo.FaultInfoService">
</bean>
<bean id="FaultInfoResource" class="com.dfe.demo.FaultInfoResource">
  <property name="faultInfoService" ref="FaultInfoService"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="ExplorationResultService"  parent="baseService" class="com.dfe.demo.ExplorationResultService">
</bean>
<bean id="ExplorationResultResource" class="com.dfe.demo.ExplorationResultResource">
  <property name="explorationResultService" ref="ExplorationResultService"/>
</bean>
```

And my server class is:

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"com/dfe/iss/config/applicationContext.xml","com/dfe/demo/yearlyplan/cxf-servlet.xml"});
JAXRSServerFactoryBean fib = (JAXRSServerFactoryBean) ctx.getBean("fis");
fib.create();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```xml
<beans>
    <jaxrs:server id="bookstore1">
        <jaxrs:properties>
            <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true"/>
        </jaxrs:properties>
    </jaxrs:server>  
</beans>
```